# Change widget from select to check box in generic class based view

Tags: django, forms, widget

Is there a quick and easy way to change the default widget on forms

For example I would like to change the select box on country to a check box.

model.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    countryChoices = (('CA','Canada'),('US','United States'),('MX','Mexico'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(choices = countryChoices, max_length=30)
    website = models.URLField()
```

views

```
class PublisherCreate(CreateView):
    model = Publisher
    fields = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state_province', 'country',  'website']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom form and customise the widget there:

```
class PublisherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta
        model = Publisher
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state_province', 'country',  'website']
        widgets = {
            'country': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
```

I've used radio select here. It doesn't really make sense to use checkboxes because you only want one choice to be selected.

Then use the form in the view:

```
class PublisherCreate(CreateView):
    model = Server
    form_class = PublisherForm
```

Comment: thank, What file do I save the publisher class in forms.py?

Comment: You can save the form it wherever you like, as long as you import it in the `views.py` where you use it. Using `forms.py` would be a good choice.

Comment: I had to move the model = Publisher and the fields = [ ......} to the  PublisherForm class but after that if worked thanks

Comment: I always forget whether it's necessary to define the model and fields in a custom form. It appears that it is required with generic class based views, but it isn't when setting `form` for a `ModelAdmin`. In this case the view also requires `model`, unless you override `template_name` or `get_template_names()`.